# How to change menu options above SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm pretty new to ssrs so apologies if this is a simple question.

When I generate a report in my browser, above the report it shows several menu options spread out vertically like below:

[image]

This takes up a lot of room and is pretty ugly, so how to I change it so that they are arrange horizontly to look more like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also approach this issue by following these steps:

Open the report from internet explorer, once you have the report opened, go to tools or click on (Alt + X), go to compatibility view, and add the server at which you are viewing the report to compatibility view list. This will fix the issue on the client level not the server level though.

Comment: This worked alright, is there a way of applying this on the server level so that all clients change?

Comment: @ruffles you need to speak to your IT administrator to add this server to the compatibility view list for all users. They can do it easily using group policy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Internet Explorer 11 and was fixed in more recent versions of SSRS.

The workaround for older versions is to edit the `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS<YourVersion>.<YourInstance>\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\ReportViewer.aspx` file and change the line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```

to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Here is the connect item: [SQL Server Reporting Services is not compatible with Internet Explorer 11](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810527/sql-server-reporting-services-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: I could not find this file anywhere on the server

Comment: @ruffles - I forgot a `Microsoft SQL Server` directory in the path. You can't find the directory or only the file?

Comment: Either.. that directory isn't under \Microsoft SQL Server or anywhere that I can see. This might be a user privilige thing making them not visible to me maybe?

Comment: @ruffles - Yes, or maybe it was installed in a non-default Directory/Drive

Comment: Possibly. I will have to check on this as I don't have access rights to the other drives